# Error when returning from a method using loops and if statements

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, methods

I have to write a method that accepts an integer to look for and returns the position of the first occurrence found or -1 if not found in an array.  This is what I have so far, however, it has an error when returning but I do not know what I am doing wrong:

```
public static int findValue (int [] z, int y) //y is the number given by the user that I need to find.
{
    for (int x = 0; x < z.length ; x++) 
    {
        if ( z[x] == y)
        {
            int w = x;
            break;
            return (w);
        }
    }
    else 
        return -1;
```

}

Comment: There cannot be a `else` clause for a `for` loop (in java)...

Comment: then what should I do to return -1 if "y" is not found?

Comment: Just remove the `else` and return... also why do you have a `break` before return inside if?

Comment: You have unreachable code below the `break;`.

Comment: I used break because I only need to return the first occurrence. If I do not break the loop isn't it going to keep going, and still return -1 if I do not use else? Sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: Return returns. If you find it you can immediately return the value since it's the first. No other code will run inside that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) `else block` is for `if statement` not `for-loop statement`.

2.) Also no need for `break;` statement, when you are returning from `if`

3.) Also no need for assignment, extra variable  `int w = x;`, just `return x` is sufficient.

```
public static int findValue (int [] z, int y) //y is the number given by the user that I need to find.
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < z.length ; x++) 
        {
            if ( z[x] == y)
            {
              return x;
            }
        } 
          return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are really close to solving this:

- **Remove the `else`** -  You do not need an `else` after the loop, because the code after the loop is reached immediately after the loop exit condition is met.
- **Remove the `break`** - `return` breaks the loop without an additional `break` statement.

That's it - the code is ready to go. As a point for style, you could remove declaration of `w`, and write `return x` for the entire body of your `if` statement. It's going to work as is, though.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems with this code. First, you can't have a `return` right after a `break` statement; the `return` statement is unreachable. Just get rid of the `break`. EDIT (in response to a comment by OP): it's important to realize that when the `return` statement executes, it immediately terminates the loop (as well as the entire method). No other code in the method will run.<sup>*</sup>

Second, you can't have an `else` without a matching `if`, and here you don't need one. If you get that far, it's because the loop finished without executing a `return`—meaning that the value was not found. So just return -1.

Also, as a matter of style, you don't need the `w` variable; returning `x` will work just as well. Put it all together and the result might look like this:

```
public static int findValue (int [] z, int y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < z.length ; x++) 
    {
        if ( z[x] == y)
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

*<sub>This is not always true. If a `return` executes inside a `try` or `catch` block that also has an associated `finally` block, then the code in the `finally` block will execute after the `return` statement finishes.</sub>